# show value variable in redirect?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

how can show value $error in redirect?
please give me example.

```
if ( ! $files )
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            redirect('hello/hi/insert_foreign');
        }
```

Comment: append it to query string and use superglobals GET to retrieve it.

Comment: create a temp variable in the session. Sometimes, the variable to store can't be put in the querystring.

Comment: [Flashdata](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is a bit out of sense if you think at the action you're doing.

A header redirect is an http request to the server, in this case to redirect to another URL; usually they carry a status code with a particular meaning, like 404 for page not found, etc. ([See a list of error codes)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). You shouldn't use it to pass arbitarty and custom information targeted at users and belonging to UI, like a response after an action, for example.

if you want to do this, you'd better use either a delayed timeout using php:

```
if ( ! $files )
        {
            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->load->view('show_error',$data);
            sleep(5);
            redirect('hello/hi/insert_foreign', 'refresh');
        }
```

Or using CI's flashdata, which is handy for showing temporary messages to users (see manual page [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) for a better explanation):

```
  $this->session->flashdata('error');
```

Or can use javascript:

In your controller:

```
$data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
$this->load->view('show_error', $data);
```

And in your view show_error.php:

```
<?php echo $error; ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var href = "<?php echo site_url('hello/hi/insert_foreing');?>";
        setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = href; }, 3000 );
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current specification, I came up with this:

```
<?php
    echo implode('<br>', $error);
?>
```

**EDIT**

Display an error on the next page. I would do it with $_SESSION. There is no point in adding anything with GET method. In fact, sessions should be much more safer, of course look better and you don't have to convert anything from GET method..instead simply get the source error from an array..

```
<?php
    if (!$files) {
        $_SESSION['upload_errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors());
        redirect('hello/hi/insert_foreign');
    } 
?>
```

**Page where you get redirected:**

```
<?php
    echo implode('<br>', $_SESSION['upload_errors']);
?>
```

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question. Anyways, this is the basic idea. And for current problem, this is the very best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! $files )
{
     $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
     $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
     redirect('hello/hi/insert_foreign');
}

//on other page
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
    $error = $_SESSION['error'];
    //output error
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
```